# video.js - updating subtitles / captions

Tags: javascript, html, video

I have setup a single video.js player that swaps in various videos dependent on the thumbnail that's clicked. For each of the videos there is a corresponding caption.vtt file. The video swaps over fine, but I can't find a way to update the selected vtt file. I can't find anything in the documentation. Is this possible? And if so, could somebody please tell me how.

Something like this would be perfect, but obviously this doesn't work...

```
myPlayer.src([
    { type: "video/mp4", src: "./video/video" + selectedVideo + ".mp4" },
    { type: "video/webm", src: "./video/video" + selectedVideo + ".webm" },
    { type: "video/ogg", src: "./video/video" + selectedVideo + ".ogv" },
    { type: "text/webvtt", src: "./video/caption" + selectedVideo + ".vtt" }
]);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated as i'm at a dead end.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try adding it to .tracks not to .src.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work, but thanks for the thought:

myPlayer.tracks([
  { type: "text/webvtt", tracks: "./video/caption" + selectedVideo + ".vtt" }
]);

The thing just stays locked on whatever the first loaded VTT is and I can't replace it with another.

Comment: type is always the same, maybe change language and src, just saying, not sure about syntax.

Comment: yeah, I've fiddled about with the syntax but can't seem to get it working. Thanks all the same

Answer (score 0):

Destroy the player and recreate it using JavaScript. That did it for me.